# Help identify this ceremony (probably 1930's London)?

Tags: identification, 1930s, 1920s, london, photograph

This image was found in a collection that suggests that it is likely to be in London, perhaps 1930 or a bit earlier. It may be the laying of a foundation stone. We'd like to identify the event. Are any of the people identifiable? Especially the chap with the big beard turning to his right.

[image: unknown London ceremony; men in clerical costume, beards, tophats]

Thanks!

Comment: The gentleman in the lower right is wearing a distinctive chain; could be masonic or civic insignia.  Appear to be naval officers in the lower left facing away.  There is a man with a fore and aft hat in the center right background. Are any of these clues for more skilled anglophiles than I?

Comment: Suspect those aren't naval officers - no epaulettes, and if it was a naval event you'd expect to see some more officers around and not just facing the crowd. I would agree with civic dignitaries, perhaps a stone-laying or similar. Note the man with shirt-sleeves rolled up and an apron in the background.

Comment: Very sorry, no higher resolution, and I don't have a print. Is the mace from some London borough? https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-a-beadle-mace-bearer-from-the-city-of-london-holds-a-ceremonial-mace-51571898.html

Comment: Could be the Lord Mayor rather than one of the boroughs (or another city entirely) - hard to say. The man next to the macebearer seems to have a sword (which would fit as well) and the collar could plausibly be the Mayor's regalia, but it's not detailed enough to say for sure it's London and not somewhere else.

Comment: No accusation, but: If you are unable to provide a higher res pic: why? It has quite the compression & res issues. IE, If no new photo, or preferably scan, *can* come forward: where did this pic come from? The more info you can provide, the better any research will go.

Comment: Why do yoiu think it is 1930s by various things e.g. crowds' hats I would have thought pre WW1 and possibly earlier.

Comment: Looking at the women's hat its definitely well before the 1930s I agree with @mmmmmm, more like WW I or before.

Comment: Speculation - I would suggest it is a foundation stone laying ceremony. To the extreme right, there appears to be a builder, and a stone about to be hoisted into place. The gentleman wearing robes and a chain looks like a mayor, and the clergyman next to him is, possibly, a Bishop, although that is just an educated guess. The second clergyman could be his chaplain. One of the men in tricorne hats appears to be holding a mace, again suggesting a civic ceremony The bearded man in the dust jacket might be the architect? . Given the costumes, query a WWI memorial? Obviously solemn/formal enough.

Comment: I have no higher resolution image because the scan was provided 12 years ago by a relative, while we were researching family history, and the original is now lost. It was speculated that the "builder" in the picture was our grandfather. His business flourished in Aldgate, London, from 1925 until about 1930. We have no late photos of him: it may not be him. My original title said "1930-ish" and somebody edited it to say 1930s. The speculation here that it is earlier is very credible. If it is pre-WWI, then it is definitely not our grandfather. Thanks for all the ideas!